Next auth, mongoose model problem - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User')
I was working on using Next auth with credentials, but I keep encountering TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User') problem whenever I import the UserModel. Here is my auth/[...nextauth]/route.js code
// authOptions.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import connectToDB from "@/lib/database";
import { compare } from "bcryptjs";
import User from "@/models/user";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        userName: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },

      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { userName, password } = credentials;

        console.log("Authorize: Received credentials:", credentials);

        try {
          // Establish database connection
          await connectToDB();

          // Query User model using the database connection
          const user = User.findOne({ userName });
          console.log("Authorize: Found user:", user);

          if (!user) {
            console.log("Authorize: User not found");
            return null;
          }

          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

          if (!passwordsMatch) {
            console.log("Authorize: Passwords don't match");
            return null;
          }

          console.log("Authorize: Authentication successful");
          return { id: user._id, name: user.name, email: user.email };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error during authorization: ", error);
          return null; // Explicitly return null in case of an error
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

Here is the code for the user schema:
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    image: String,
    color: String,
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    departmentID: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Department",
      required: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["admin", "teacher", "student", "admin-teacher"],
      required: true,
    },
    sex: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["female", "male"],
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["active", "deprecated", "inactive"],
      default: "active",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }    
);

const User = models.User || model("User", UserSchema);

export default User;

What exactly is the problem here?
I tried console logging the errors and checked Model Export/Import and checked the database connection as well.

Please add some more supporting code or screenshot.

Does this answer your question? TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

I had the same problem. Fixed by using this:
let User;
try {
  User = mongoose.model('User');
} catch {
  User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
}

